# Could you protect a crew from space radiation with fuel?

Tags: mars, rockets, fuel, radiation

Are there big differences in the amount of radiation if you would put the crew compartment (on the journey to Mars) inside the LOX/LH2 fuel tank? I know that there are similarities with other question, but this is only meant with its own rocket fuel.

Comment: I don't know what kind of fuel you're thinking of, but I know *I* wouldn't want to ride in the fuel tank.

Comment: LOX/LH2.. I only wonder, if this Could be possible...

Comment: So your habitat would have to be designed to prevent implosion instead of rupture.

Comment: But would LOX or LH2 prevent it from radiation?....nearly as good as water?

Comment: @called2voyage if your in space and there is an explosion in your fuel tank does it really matter where you are in relationship to the tank?

Comment: @JamesJenkins I wasn't really thinking of an explosion of the fuel tank as much as some of the other dangers of fuel.

Comment: @called2voyage: with LOX/LH2 the only hazards are explosion and temperature. H2 outgassing can be solved by not having the tank and the crew compartment share a wall. A double wall with vacuum in between would keep the H2 away from the crew.

Comment: @Hobbes The question was originally about fuel in general and was only later narrowed to specifically LOX/LH2.

Comment: A crew compartment is going to be a big heat source - there will be waste heat you have to get rid of. Putting it in the middle of cryogenic tanks will certainly eliminate any surplus heat problem for the crew compartment, but   you probably don't want to be putting heat sources inside your cryo storage if you need to keep the stores cold for extended durations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, low-Z shield would work (generally, water or polyethylene). However, LH2 is famously prone to seeping through seemingly solid walls, and making habitable space fit inside the fuel tank would put you at a disadvantage:

- Crew habitat has to be at room temperature (293K).
- LH2 has to be kept at the temperature of 20K.
- You would have to increase insulation between the habitat and the tank to reduce thermal losses (and correspondingly, hydrogen boil-off which is mass wasted, pure and simple). Instead of a cylinder with hemispherical ends, you'd have to produce a less efficient and more expensive vessel.
- Even then, the crew would be freezing cold, and thermal design would be unnecessarily bulky and risky.
- If you spend the last drops of fuel on Trans-Earth injection you'll have no protection from cosmic rays during the return voyage.
- Another important part of that disadvantage is LH2's low density: 70.85 $kg/m^3$ instead of water's 1000 or ice's 917.

Comment: LH2 is not used in deep space, only in first stages because of all mentioned disadvantages. So, instead of LH2 there will be hydrazine which is better for this purpose

Comment: @MadBender - the OP explicitly asked about LOX/LH2. Hydrazine has lower Isp, and there may come a day of zero-boiloff cryo storage.